# MySQL Update one table, but use data from two other tables as part of the update

Tags: php, mysql, join

I wish to update one table in my database, the data is from a php POST. (It is a page where multiple edits on rows can take place at once, then it processes them all at once after) and i want it so for each "row" or "loop", it builds a single query that can update all the rows at once.

What i want to do, is in the query, select data from two other tables.
E.g

```
Posted data:
 - Task = "Check current Sponsors"
 - User Assigned = "Dan"
 - Start Meeting = "Mar 1st"
 - Meetings Required = 2
```

And for User Assigned, i want it to basically do this query:

> SELECT `id` FROM `team` WHERE `fullname` LIKE 'Dan'

And for the start meeting, i want it to do this query:

> SELECT `id` FROM `meetings` WHERE `starttime`='".strtotime("Mar
>   1st")."'

-- strtotime() makes a unix timestamp from a string.

but i want it to do that for each "task" that gets submitted. (It is queued up via javascript and it sends them all into the same post request)

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Table Structures:

Tasks:

```
id | startmid | length | task           | uid | completed
1  | 2        | 1      | Check Sponsors | 1   | 0
```

Meetings: (Joined by startmid)

```
id | maintask | starttime  | endtime
1  | Sponsors | 1330007400 | 1330012800
```

Team: (Joined by uid)

```
id | fullname | position     | class | hidden
1  | Team     | All Members  | black | 0
2  | Dan S    | Team Manager | green | 0
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what your update statement is now and maybe a pseudo code of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: **UPDATE `maintasks` SET mt.`task` = CASE mt.`id` WHEN '1' THEN 'Check Current Sponsors' END , mt.`starttime` = CASE mt.`id` WHEN '1' THEN '' END , mt.`endtime` = CASE mt.`id` WHEN '1' THEN '1330556400' END WHERE `id` IN ('1')** Is what i have at the moment, but thats copied from my other script, i have no idea where to start with making it work for this, ive looked up on google and havent found an answer that does many rows in one query, like this query does with no outside table contents

Comment: as u hv mentioned, "MySQL Update one table, but use data from two other tables as part of the update", i would like to know the reationship of the "tasks" table to be update and the other 2 tables structure to help u out

Comment: I described that with the two other queries in the question. When the tasks table gets updated, i want it to get the "id" of the user from the "team" table but via a "LIKE `fullname`='Dan'", and the meeting date similar, but via a timestamp

Comment: Honestly it still isn't clear. I think you should rethink your strategy. If you're displaying the records to update on the screen before hand, couldn't you store their primary keys in a hidden input to submit back? Even if we find the right query it's going to be extremely slow.

Comment: Their primary keys would change, if it displays "Ben" as the team member, and its changed to "Dan". The primary key would be different because its a different user. Basically, for the "uid" and "mid" fields of the "tasks" table, (I'll edit the question and add in table structure) i want them to query another table to get their value

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following construct:

```
UPDATE mytable( col1, col2 )
SELECT col1_val, col2_val
FROM someothertables
WHERE cond1 = cond1;
```

Comment: Surely that makes multiple queries? For other parts of my control panel that uses a similar editing feature. It has an SQL like **UPDATE `meetings` SET `task` = CASE WHEN '1' THEN 'Task for ID1' WHEN '2' THEN 'Task for ID2' END WHERE `id` IN (1,2)**
So it updates many rows in one query, which is what i want to achieve as i dont want too much traffic between the web and mysql server